# Request helping for writing HTTP Request in Android

Tags: android

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.*;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
//import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try
        {
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.yahoo.com");
            HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);

            if(rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                //String str = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
                InputStream is = rp.getEntity().getContent();           
                String str = is.toString();

                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(str);
                setContentView(tv);

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("halo,baby.");
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

the above is my code.
but it seems there are some problems here.
So, Anyone can give me some ideas on it?
Thank you.

Carmen Lau

Comment: What is the problem, that you are facing? Error or wrong behavior? Do you have to use HttpClient and have you tried HttpUrlConnection?

Comment: Yes, what is the error you're getting? The code looks OK to me just giving it a quick once-over .

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the problem is it's hard to diagnose, but I suspect the following line isn't what you want:

```
String str = is.toString();
```

`Object.toString()` returns "a string containing a concise, human-readable description of this object." Which is not always what you'd expect. You'll probably actually want to pull the data out by hand with something like:

```
byte[] readBytes; // create an empty byte array
is.read(readBytes); // read from the InputStream and put input in the byte array
String str = new String(readBytes); // creat a new String from the byte array
```

Then set the text on the `TextView` to `str` like you were already doing.

Answer (score 1):

You may visit this website.
there has an article about http request response from android application.

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-get-post-and-multipart-post-requests/

Answer (score 0):

**For mldj and MattC,** 
The problem is I cannot print out the response message. 
As my coding, the import parts also post out, but I don't know why they become in Black letters only in the beginning of my coding.

Actually, I want to send a get request to Yahoo and get back the response and print it out.
but now I open my app and it is blank.

So, I am not sure the problem is 
**(1)** I using the wrong method to print it out
OR
**(2)** my app cannot send the request to Yahoo and haven't get back any response for me from the beginning to now on.

**For fiXedd,**
I will try your suggested code tonight. I think it can solve the problem if I really use a wrong method for print out the response message. Thank you very much.